# Activar Pestaña en pagina WEB con VBA Excel

Tags: vba

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para poder automatizar el llenado de un formulario en una página web. Todo bien, hasta que me tope con una pestaña, la cual he intentado activarla por medio de VBA, he introducido el código aqui de la siguiente manera:

```
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
If MyHTML_Element.href = "#tabImpuestos" Then
    MyHTML_Element.Click
    Exit For
End If
Next
```

Esta es la pestaña en cuestion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la línea HTML es:

```
 <a aria-expanded="false"  style=""  onclick="deshabilitaBotonAceptar();  href="#tabImpuestos" data-toggle="tab"> Impuestos </a>
```

¿Que puedo hacer al respecto?

Comment: Bienvenido C.Villa, te aconsejo revisar la redacción de tu pregunta : " he inintroducir el código aquítentado con lo siguiente" ?, saludos

Comment: mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta de ser necesario. Que es lo que quieres lograr? el click? y eso no funciona?

Comment: Una disculpa. Asi es. Quiero que se haga "click" y se active la pestaña. Pero, hasta ahora no lo he logrado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar ejecutar la función

```
HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript("deshabilitaBotonAceptar();")
```

O mostrar más html por favor.